# How do you login with a different account in Stack Overflow?

Tags: support

I have made a new account on Stack Exchange. I wish to use that for Stack Overflow. The problem is, it won't let me. I am already logged in from my google account in Stack Overflow. When I try to remove the account from 'my logins', it says that I can't remove my only login. When I try to add my new account to 'my logins', it gives me no clear option. It says I can sign up with Google, facebook, blogger, etc... It does not give an option to directly sign in. It says I can enter my 'OpenID' but I have no idea where to find that. Can someone assist me ?